# mklink fails from Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, msbuild, cmd

I have next pre build event:

```
cmd /C mklink /D /J "$(ProjectDir)SomeDir" "$(ProjectDir)"
```

This is expanded in(copied from MSBuild output):

```
cmd /C mklink /D /J "C:\Dir-1\Dir-2\other-dirs-here\SomeDir" "C:\Dir-1\Dir-2\other-dirs-here\"
```

When running the build with this build event the symbolic link is not created, but when I copy exactly the expanded output of Visual Studio in command line the link is created.

Do you know why?

EDIT: I have administrator rights on the computer. Both Visual Studio and Command Prompt have "Administrator" on top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem - the previous command in the build event was:

```
$(ANDROID_HOME)/tools/android.bat update project my-project-settings
```

and for some weird reasons prevented all commands after it to run...